# Spring Boot Custom @Async Wrap Callable

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am working on an application that supports multi tenancy. The tenant's unqiue identifier is stored in a thread local and can be accessed via some service.
To allow parallel processing, I have created a Callable wrapper, sets the thread local variable:

```
class TenantAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
  private final String tenantName;
  private final Callable<T> delegate;

  TenantAwareCallable(Callable<T> delegate, String tenantName) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.tenantName = tenantName;
  }

  @Override
  public T call() throws Exception {
    // set threadlocal
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenantName(tenantName);

    try {
      return delegate.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     // log and handle
    } finally {
     TenantContext.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

This can already be used in the application. But what I would like to have is some custom `@Async` annotation, like for example `@TenantAwareAsync` or `@TenantPreservingAsync`, that wraps the callable, created by Spring in this one and then executes it.

Is there some way to get started with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution for this, so I think sharing it here might help some people some day.

I solved it not by using the `TenantAwareCallable` but by customizing the Executor service. I chose to extend Spring's ThreadPoolTaskScheduler (since this is what we use in the project).

```
public class ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskScheduler extends ThreadPoolTaskScheduler {
  @Override
  protected ScheduledExecutorService createExecutor(int poolSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
    return new ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskExecutor(poolSize, threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
  }
}
```

The actual setting of the context data is done in a customized `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
public class ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

  public ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskExecutor(int poolSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
    super(poolSize, threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
  }

  @Override
  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Callable<V> callable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new ContextAwareTask<V>(task);
  }

  @Override
  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new ContextAwareTask<V>(task);
  }

  static private class ContextAwareTask<T> implements RunnableScheduledFuture<T> {

    private final RunnableScheduledFuture<T> delegate;

    private final TenantContextHolder multitenantContextHolder;
    private final LoggingContextHolder loggingContextHolder;
    private final SecurityContext securityContext;

    ContextAwareTask(RunnableScheduledFuture<T> delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;

      multitenantContextHolder = TenantContextHolder.newInstance();
      loggingContextHolder = LoggingContextHolder.newInstance();
      securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      multitenantContextHolder.apply();
      loggingContextHolder.apply();
      SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

      delegate.run();

      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      loggingContextHolder.clear();
      multitenantContextHolder.clear();
    }

    // all other methods are just delegates
  }
}
```

The Holders are basically just objects to store context state and apply it in the new thread.

```
public class TenantContextHolder {

  private String tenantName;

  public static TenantContextHolder newInstance() {
    return new TenantContextHolder();
  }

  private TenantContextHolder() {
    this.tenantName = TenantContext.getCurrentTenantName();
  }

  public void apply() {
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenantName(tenantName);
  }

  public void clear() {
    TenantContext.clear();
  }
}
```

The custom implementation of the Scheduler can then be configured in the Spring environment.

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
  private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    if (taskScheduler == null) {
      taskScheduler = new ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
    return taskScheduler;
  }

  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    return taskScheduler();
  }
}
```